# How to compare a column with comma seperated numbers and a specific number using REGEXP in mysql

Tags: mysql, regex

I have a column with values like 24,25,26,27 and 
I want to match 24 (or some other number). 
I like to do it based on regex don't know how to do?

I want the matching should be clear like 24,25,26 should match with 24 not 243

Comment: I highly recommend the following book [`Avoiding the Pitfalls of Database Programming`](http://www.amazon.com/SQL-Antipatterns-Programming-Pragmatic-Programmers/dp/1934356557/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1382728316&sr=8-1&keywords=9781934356555). If you designed your database in a good way in the first place, you wouldn't be hacking around like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at

### [FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

```
SELECT FIND_IN_SET('24','24,25,26 ');
```

> Note Please don't store vales as comma separated instead normalize
>   your structure

Comment: Thanks dianuj, I am not so familiar with db designing.